# Reducing solar panel voltage (30V) where DC to DC regulator switches off at 28 V or above

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I have purchased a flexible solar panel to charge my caravan batteries via a DC to DC charger/regulator which turns off when the voltage gets above 28.2 V. The panel is rated 28.5 Vopen circuit, 200 W, max power volts 23.2 V, [9.1 amps].

In bright sun my volt meter reads 30-31 V and this causes my regulator to shut down. The adviser for the regulator manufacturer suggested putting a load across the + & -, aglobe 24 V. These have been popping.

Is there a better way with out sacrificing too much power for charging?
thanks in anticipation, Pete Moonta

Comment: You might find upgrading the charge controller is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

A set of 3 series diodes with 0.7 to 1 volt forward voltage drop and 10 amp rating should be plenty to drop that max voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Put a secondary load on your panel. If you're reading 30-31 volts on the panel output, it's clear that your charger is not drawing much current. This means that you have power to spare. With a bigger load your panel output voltage will drop.

For better performance, put a monitor on your charger output current, and when it is high enough you can disconnect the secondary load.